# Why I am getting 'HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL' error?

Tags: java, servlets

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet
{
private void sendLoginPage (HttpServletResponse res, HttpServletRequest req, boolean error)
throws ServletException,IOException
{
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter o = res.getWriter();        
    o.println("<html><head><title>Sample Login Page</title></head><body>Welcome to Login Page : ");
    if (error)
    o.println("<fieldset><legend>Login Form : </legend>");
    o.println("Login Failed, Please Try Again");
    o.println("<form method="+"post"+">");
    o.println("<br/><input type="+"text"+"value="+"username"+"/>");
    o.println("<br/><input type="+"password"+"value="+""+"/>");
    o.println("<br/><input type="+"button"+"value="+"Submit"+"/>");
    o.println("</form></fieldset></body></html>");
}

public void doGet (HttpServletResponse res, HttpServletRequest req)
throws ServletException,IOException
{
    sendLoginPage ( res, null, false ) ;
}

public void doPost (HttpServletResponse res, HttpServletRequest req)
throws ServletException,IOException
{
    String username = req.getParameter("username");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    if ( username.equals("*******") && password.equals("*******") )
    {
        res.sendRedirect ("http://localhost:7001/ten/r1");
    }
    else 
    {
        sendLoginPage ( res, null, true ) ;
    }
}           
}
```

Well this Servlet compiles okay without any errors and also gets deployed on the server
but shows this error when trying to access it through url :

> **HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL**

Comment: You're allowed to indent your code in order to increase readability. Your IDE might even be able to do it automatically at the press of a key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest parameters reversed on your methods.

Side note: Using the @Override annotation on overridden methods *would* cause a compile error for this (assuming you're using at least Java 1.5)

Comment: +1 - Since the parameters are reversed, the OP's code is not overriding methods in the superclass, and hence they are (probably) not being called at all.

Comment: the signature for doGet() and doPost is 
`public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
doPost(req,resp);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
//process the incoming request
}`

Comment: thanx :) it works now. ! well i am a newbie so i thought reversing parameters would work anyway. but i forgot about overidden methods.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when my method call

"super.doGet(req, resp)" or "super.doPost(req, resp)" .

After i removed above super class calling from the doGet and doPost it worked fine.

Infact those super class calling codes were inserted by the Eclipse IDE template.